# UITableView crashing when scrolled (iOS 7.1.2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create a `UITableView` when a user presses a button, set it's delegate and data source to the current controller (which implements both `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols), add it as a subview to the controller's view and implement the data source methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Whenever I scroll the table view, the application crashes with

```
[UITableView currentPage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11365c00
```

where `0x11365c00` is the `tableView`. If I don't set the `tableView's` delegate and only set the data source, it doesn't crash. This behavior is the same if I return 0 in `numberOfRowsInSection`, so that nothing is added to the `tableView` and there is no crash related to my data. Any help would be great!

Comment: add snippet where you are using currentPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash occurs because you are sending a message `-currentPage` to an object that can't handle it. 
And actually tableviews doesn't have this method in their interfaces, unless you are using a category. So the question is which object n your implementation file should handle this message?

Comment: Sorry, stupid issue, and my question was incomplete. The controller also implements UIScrollViewDelegate and contains a scrollView for whom it is it's delegate, before adding the tableView. The controller was receiving scrollView delegate callbacks for the tableView and performing some logic without checking which scrollView it was.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

```
[someObjectHere currentPage]; // Here someObjectHere is really a table view(UITableView type)
```

If you have table view class and forgot to define the currentPage method, then define it there. That's y it crashed the app.

If you have currentPage method in your view controller then you have to make sure that someObjectHere is a your View controller.

```
 [self currentPage];
```